# Python erro Na importação framework Flask

Tags: python, aplicação-web, flask

após instalar o python e declarar variáveis de ambiente, ao criar uma página e tentar executar pelo Prompt de comando emite o seguinte erro :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: cannot import name 'Flask' from 'flask' (unknown location)
```

Comment: Já instalou ele?

Comment: sim instalei desinstalei e instalei de novo, mas sempre apresenta o mesmo erro.

Comment: instalei o django, e da algo parecido acho que é algum erro que cometi com a instalação das dependências pip/ virtualenv , mas mesmo reinstalando da problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não pode chamar o arquivo flask.py porque ele está tentando importar o nome Flask de si mesmo. É simples, tente nomear o arquivo app.py ou algo diferente de Flask e ele vai funcionar.

Comment: Como concluiu que o arquivo se chama `flask.py`?

Comment: Pelo from flask import Flask, mas principalmente porque eu já tinha visto isso antes com um amigo e quando fui olhar  o código para ele tava lá o flask,py.

Comment: E quanto a `File "app.py", line 1, in <module>`?

Comment: instalei Django é mais fácil